# KIVY: 'float' has no attributes 'ids'

Tags: python, function, object, kivy, clock

I am trying to make a clock which is just a label update every second with the current time. Each time I try to update the label I am thrown this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Nitro\Documents\MirOS\MirOS-core.py", line 33, in currentTime
 self.ids.current_time.text = timeData
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

I did a little research into the kivy.Clock function and I found out that this is most likely happening because the clock function calls the currentTime() and includes a delta time argument which is what causes the AttributeError. Unfortunately, I need the **self** argument to stay where it is as otherwise my label does not update and I am thrown more errors.

Here is my `.py` file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FallOutTransition
import time

sm = ScreenManager(transition = FallOutTransition())

Window.clearcolor = 0, 0, 0, 1
Window.size = 1920, 1080
Window.fullscreen = True

class StartUP(Screen):

    def SystemCheck(self):
        sm.current = 'active_home'
        print('WORKING')

    class StartUPCavas(Widget):
        pass

class ActiveHome(Screen):

    class ActiveHomeCanvas(Widget):
        pass

    class ActiveClock(Widget):

        def currentTime(self):
            timeData = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            self.ids.current_time.text = timeData

        Clock.schedule_interval(currentTime, 1)


class MirOSApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(StartUP(name = 'startup'))
        sm.add_widget(ActiveHome(name = 'active_home'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MirOSApp().run()
```

Here is the `.kv` file:

```
#kivy 2.1.0

<StartUP>:

    StartUPCavas:

        Image:
            source: 'images/MirOS.png'
            texture: self.texture
            size_hint_y: None
            width: 300
            center_x: root.width / 2
            center_y: root.height / 2

        Button:
            center_x: root.width / 2
            center_y: (root.height / 2) - 100
            on_press:
                root.SystemCheck()

<ActiveHome>:

    ActiveHomeCanvas:

    ActiveClock:

        Label:

            id: current_time

            text: ''
            font_size: 40
            font_name: 'fonts/bahnschrift.ttf'
            center_x: root.width / 2
            center_y: root.height / 2
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

I am really confused and have tried to solve this issue on my own but I can't seem to find any solution. Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about the delta time argument (`dt`). That argument is being passed into the `currentTime()` method, but the `currentTime()` method is expecting to receive the `self`. So when that method does a `self.ids`, it is trying to access the `ids` attribute of `dt`, causing the error.

In order to provide the `self` argument, you must call the `currentTime()` method as an instance method of `ActiveHome` (since that is where that `id` is defined).

You can fix this by modifying your `ActiveHome` class like this:

```
class ActiveHome(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ActiveHome, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.currentTime, 1)

    def currentTime(self, dt):
        timeData = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ids.current_time.text = timeData
```

This arrangement schedules the calls to `currentTime()` in an `__init__()` method, and the `currentTime()` method handles the correct arguments.

Comment: I will try this and will come back to let you know if it worked. Thanks for writing!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for a day or so and I've felt so lost. God bless!